# Android: AppCompatPreferenceActivity as a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, appcompatactivity

I implemented my preferenceActivity with extending AppCompatPreferenceActivity. But now I got a tablayout and I would like to get this preference screen inside this tablayout. The easiest way would be to have this preference activity as a fragment.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? What is the best practice for using AppCompatPreferenceActivity for Fragments?

Comment: maybe [`PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment) or [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate most of the code to [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v14/preference/PreferenceFragment.html).

Keep in mind fragments themselves are not as robust as Activities, if you have multiple `PreferenceScreen`s, You might need to implement extra logic to navigate between those as specified in the documentation.